# Refactor a simple return statements in js of a sorting function

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

```
sortComponents (a, b) {
  if (!a) {
    return 1
  }
  if (!b) {
    return -1
  }
  return this.keyedComponentTypes[a].text > this.keyedComponentTypes[b].text ? -1 : 1
},
```

Is there any way to summaries/simplify first two return statements to one? I don't wan't to use ternary operators to change it to single statement and make code complex.

Comment: You could combine them all as a nested ternary, but I would leave it as is because this it difficult to read, something like: `return !a ? 1 : (!b ? -1 : (this.keyedComponentTypes[a].text > this.keyedComponentTypes[b].text ? -1 : 1));`

Comment: would `sortComponents (a, b) => !a ? 1 : !b ? -1 : this.keyedComponentTypes[a].text > this.keyedComponentTypes[b].text ? -1 : 1` work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `||` statement to return -1 when your condition and `!b` is true.`

We also know that if `a` was undefined ( `!a` )  it would return `1` so we make sure that to return that `a` is define, otherwise, we return 1.

```js
let keyedComponentTypes = [
  {
    text: 'b'
  },
  {
    text: 'a'
  },
  {
    text: 'e'
  },
  {
    text: 'd'
  },
  {
    text: 'c'
  },
]


function originalSortComponents (a, b) {
  if (!a) {
    return 1
  }
  if (!b) {
    return -1
  }
  return keyedComponentTypes[a].text > keyedComponentTypes[b].text ? -1 : 1
}

function improvedSortComponent(a,b) {
  return a && ((keyedComponentTypes[a].text > keyedComponentTypes[b].text) || !b) ? -1 : 1
}

let array = [0,undefined,1,2,3,undefined,4]
console.log(array.sort(originalSortComponents));

console.log(array.sort(improvedSortComponent));
```

You can see it returns the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Adding more ternary or logical operator would make code difficult to read.

Comment: @MTauqeer I agree but your asked for a refractor of that. If your code was working before, i don't see why it would be pertinent to refractor it. In the end, there is no good answer to your question.

Comment: It is possible for this sort to attempt `keyedComponentTypes[b].text` when `b` is `null` which leads to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's how I would do it

```
sortComponents (a, b) 
{
  const c = this.keyedComponentTypes[a].text > this.keyedComponentTypes[b].text;
  return (!a || !c) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: 'a' and 'b' can be undefined, so can't directly use it with  keyedComponentTypes array

Comment: If there's no `a`, then `this.keyedComponentTypes[a].text` is an error.

Comment: oh well check out Nicolas' answer, he figured it out :-)

Comment: @FuméeNoire Thank you, however, i'm not even sure that's what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following if you want to keep just less return statements as possible (although I do not see a big deal in having shortcircuit return statements at the beginning if instead you will lose readability)

```
const first = !!this.keyedComponentTypes[a] ? this.keyedComponentTypes[a].text : '';

const second = !!this.keyedComponentTypes[b] ? this.keyedComponentTypes[b].text : '';

return (second || '').localeCompare(first || '');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with

```
sortComponents (a, b) {
  if (!a || !b) {
    return !a ? -1 : 1
  }
  return this.keyedComponentTypes[a].text > this.keyedComponentTypes[b].text ? 1 : -1
}
```